# Obtain transfer function from FEM Model

Tags: fft, transfer-function

I'am getting Transfer function from FEM Model of Simply supported rectangular plate

i do random vibration input force $x(t)$ and measured displacement $y(t)$

In matlab, because that is noise free data, I obtain $h(t)$ from IFFT(FFT($y(t)$)/FFT($x(t)$)).

Transfer function in frequency domain is quite similar compared to FEM model

but impulse response h(t) is shown below
[image]

I don't know what factor affect to h(t)

what is the problem? Thank you

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
fs = 2000
Total time is 1s

input force is [image]

output is plate displacement
[image]

'''

Y = fft(output);
X = fft(input);
H = Y./X;

h = ifft(H);

'''

Plate vibration is linear system right?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code. How does the impulse response from the FEM look like? Did you compare both amplitude and phase from the transfer function ?

Comment: Please see editted post

Comment: if dampling is very~~ low, this is non-linear?